# Horizontal line chart using categories in y-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, linechart

I planning to develop a horizontal line chart using Amchat library. and I need to arrange my categories in y axis. I have tried many ways but couldn't find a solution. Is there a way That I can set category in amchart y-axis. I have attached a image of a sample design.

Sample Design :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEShm.png